# How to use a LinkedStack prdefined from a .h in qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a LinkedStack.h and i have defined some methods.My question is how to I include that file in Qt creator and how do i write it so I can define a variable of type LinkedStack in my GUI program

In the main.cpp i used for testing in CodeBlocks for my .h i made the variable like this:

```
    LinkedStack <int> myStack;
    myStack.push(20);
```

Comment: I included the file like:
#include "LinkedStack.h"

Comment: If you `#include` it and the `.cpp` file is linked into your project once compiled, it should be fine. What's the problem and/or error you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `.pro` file is not right. You need to add the header file to `HEADERS` in your .pro file:

```
HEADERS  += LinkedStack.h
```

And if there's a source file for that header you need to add it to `SOURCES` in your .pro file:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
           LinkedStack.cpp
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's just what I needed!